# Visual C++ - Count files within directory

Tags: c++, file, directory

I guess it simple question but I cannot find how to write it in the proper way.

I have to count all *jpg, *png, *gif files within a folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [Boost::Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
  int i =  std::count_if(fs::directory_iterator("/your/path/here/"),
                         fs::directory_iterator(), 
                         [](const fs::directory_entry& e) { 
                              return e.path().extension() == ".png";
                         });
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using VC11, you could also use the `<filesystem>` header.  Just replace `boost::filesystem` with `std::tr2::sys` and this code should work exactly the same.